# Can you download the entire Amplify webapp?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, frontend, aws-cli, aws-amplify

I'm trying to debug an existing Amplify app, which most likely boils down to changing some links. However, I can't locate where the app's source code is stored, which makes me think it was just dragged and dropped rather than deployed from a repository. There is some code in CodeCommit, but that's pointing to another Amplify app, most likely the dev version of the above.

I tried:

```
amplify pull --appId xxxxxxxxxx --envName prod
```

But that only pulls the backend, which is not a problem for now. I would like to access the App.js from src and make some changes to it.

The best starting point, I believe, would be to download the project from Amplify somehow. But is it possible?

Comment: Normally with Amplify, the backend and frontend are together in one repository.
Is your Amplify app connected in the Amplify console (https://console.aws.amazon.com/amplify) or directly in S3?

Comment: It's connected to the console, but where a link to the repository should be - there's an empty field.